# Why is $E_{\lambda}$ the kernel of the linear map $\alpha-\lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The book starts the chapter on Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors, and goes that this statement is obvious. Here $E_{\lambda}$ stands for the set of vectors $v$ such that $α(v) = λv$, for any scalar $\lambda$.

Could somebody provide some intuition why is that obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean that $(\alpha - \lambda I) (v) = 0$?

Comment: Perhaps you should recall the definition of *kernel*, because this should be self-evident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha(v) = \lambda v$ if and only if $\alpha(v) - \lambda v = 0$ if and only if $(\alpha - \lambda I)(v) = 0$.

Comment: now I get it. thanks!